# What is the meaning of "faire clouc"

Tags: sens

La poule cependant semblait écouter guère; **elle avait fait clouc, clouc, clouc,** puis  elle était partie, sans entendre les derniéres paroles.

This line is from "Patachou" by Tristan Derème.

> I can't unde stand the meaning of "faire clouc"
>   Is this a dialect of Basque?

I am glad  if somebody kindly teach me.

Answer (score 9):

I think that in this case "*clouc*" just attempts to reproduce the sound that a *poule* makes - I know those animal sounds are entirely different in Japanese :-) I am not sure whether it is a dialect or not, I think it is just an [onomatopoeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia), like "*tic tac*" for a clock ... Another, more standard onomatopoeia in French would be "Cot-cot, Cot-cot-codêêêc".

Comment: Interesting remark [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_mots_et_expressions_du_Sud-Ouest_de_la_France) (at *clouque*).

Comment: @Laure I'll change my answer slightly to reflect that it might be from the Sud-Ouest de la France. "Cot-cot, Cot-cot-codêêêc" is maybe more standard.

Comment: @Hiroshi Thank you so much for your answer. It is so helpful for me!!

Answer (score 4):

In English, we say that hens cluck. It is a clucking sound.

The site below shows this means cluck.

"vu la saison il y a de fortes chances pour qu'elle couve, , si quand on le touche elle glousse de mécontentement, et gonfle les plumes, que quand elle sort elle fait "clouc clouc", c'est qu'elle couve."

http://www.poulesoieclub.com/t5887-faire-decouver-une-poule

La poule fait clouc.
The hen clucks or is clucking.

Comment: Considering my user name, I should probably know this, but is "hen" one of those words (kind of like "fish," I guess) that can be pluralized without an "s"? If so, never mind, but if not, did you mean "... we say that hen**s** cluck" in the 1st sentence?

Comment: @Hiroshi  Thank you so much for your  information!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I would be curious to hear how many native French speakers were told "clouc" for the sound of the hen when they were kids, and how many were told "Cot-cot-codêêêc".

Comment: @Papa Poule Comme je ne suis une personne humaine, la perfection m'échappe toujours.

Comment: @Frank I said: in English we say that a hen clucks. And that that French site shows this means cluck. I did not say anything about dictionaries or what native French speakers say, did I? How much more careful should I be?

Comment: And the reason of this outburst is... ? More interesting - the guy that mentions "clouc, clouc" is apparently from Toulouse, which could be in line with what @Laure  was saying above.

Comment: It is not an outburst.

Answer (score 1):

*Clouc clouc* is not known as is in French but is likely from Occitan and not Basque.

In Occitan, *cloc* pronounced \kluk\ = *clouc* is the name of the sound made by a *cloca*, a broody hen. This sound is transcribed as *cot cot cot codet/codec* in French.

Its root can also be found in Spanish where *cloquear* and *gallina clueca* are both related to a broody hen. In French, the equivalent would be *cocotte*.

While *clouc* is undoubtedly an onomatopoeia like its English counterparts "cluck" and "cackle". *Clouc* might also be given a Latin root: the verb *glocare* which gave the French *glousser*.

Wikipedia suggests an indo-European root, **klag*, so that might be a very ancient onomatopoeia.

References: [cloc](http://www.panoccitan.org/diccionari.aspx?diccion=cloca&lenga=oc) [cloca](http://www.etymologie-occitane.fr/2011/08/cloca-cloucho/) [clueca](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/llueca.418823/) [cloquear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9UVuotX) [glocare](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/glocio#la) [clangare](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/clango#la)